# splitable jumper wires question

Tags: arduino-uno, wires

I just received my starter kit from oddwires.com today and it came with a split-able ribbon cable for prototyping. I was curious if it is possible to split each wire off and use only what I need to for the tutorials or is that a bad idea? I am very excited to start playing around and learning this as it has been a interest of mine for many years.

Comment: Which starter kit? None of the ones under "oddWires Kits for Arduino" has (or shows) a ribbon cable.

Comment: the uno deluxe, but they called it "Perfect premium jumper wire pack - combinations female/male, male/male in 6"/10" lengths (40 wires)". This is what was sent to me though [link](http://www.oddwires.com/dupont-jumper-wire-ribbon-cable-40-jumper-wires-splittable-high-quality-male-male-20cm/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each wire in the Dupont ribbon cable is is independent, and does not hold onto its neighbors with any real force. You can split them or join multiple wires together using larger connectors as desired.

Comment: Okay I didn't want to accidentally damage anything before I had a chance to use it. (I would hit the checkmark, but I am sure my rep isn't high enough)